# Issue with Conditional Multiple Drop Down in Google Sheets Sript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Newbie to Google scripts here. I've searched on here and googled this until my fingers are sore and I'm struggling to overcome what is probably a simple issue, but I'm new to coding in Google Sheets and have limited experience in coding in Excel. There are many threads disussing coding drop downs, but I'm trying to get myself back on track so I can follow the series of tutorial videos through the next steps and I can find anything that resolves the issue.

I am following a video tutorial to set up some basic userforms to allow me to use them on some projects I'm working on. It includes a series of code copied in from Bootstrap.

Video here: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKksZpsuJJM&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemuzTNWeHd8HziGVNzSlWACh&index=3).

The issue is that when I run the UserForm after exactly matching to code in the video, the drop down isn't calling any of the items from the list in the sheet. I've gone through this so many times and cannot find any error related to inaccuracies in the copied code.

I really want to get to the point where the code runs properly, coded as is shown in the tutorial, so I can then start to modify it to suit my needs knowing that I can fall back to the functioning code if I make a mistake.

If anyone can take a look and help me out I would really, really, appreciate it.

Code Below:

**backend code (script file)**

```js
function getDropDownArray(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Dropdown Options");
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() -1, 1).getValues();
}
```

**Frontend Code (HTML file)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">


    <div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item-name">item-name</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="item-name">    
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="qty-received">qty-received</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty-received">
      </div>
   
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton" >Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

    function afterButtonClicked(){
      var item = document.getElementById("item-name");
      var qty = document.getElementById("qty-received");

      var rowData = {item: item.value,qty: qty.value};

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);
    }
    function afterSubmit(e){
      var qty = document.getElementById("qty-received");
      qty.value="";
    }

    function afterSidebarLoads(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropDownArrayReturned).getDropDownArray();
    }

    function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays){
      var item = document.getElementById("item-name");
      
      arrayofArrays.forEach(function(r){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = r[0];
        item.appendChild(option);
      });
    }

    document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterSidebarLoads);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've copied this code from the tutorial exactly as it is displayed in the video. I've been over and over it to make sure, correcting some issues with typos etc along the way. This still doesn't work but appears to work perfectly in the video.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, the values from `getDropDownArray()` are given by `arrayOfArrays` of `afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays)`. But, at the following part,

```
arrayofArrays.forEach(function(r){
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = r[0];
  item.appendChild(option);
});
```

`arrayofArrays` is used. This is not the same with `arrayOfArrays`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. So, please modify the function `afterDropDownArrayReturned` as follows and test it again.

#### Modified script:

```
function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
  var item = document.getElementById("item-name");
  arrayOfArrays.forEach(function (r) { // <--- Modified
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = r[0];
    item.appendChild(option);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are a hero, thank you so much!!!